# NSMutableArray to NSArray Error

Tags: xcode

I found a sample code that takes an NSArray and converts it to video. The problem is I have my own code that takes a sequence of photos and save them into an NSMutableArray. I tried to convert it to an NSArray but I am hitting a road block. Every method I tried is giving me an NSConcreteMutableData CGImage unrecognized selector sent to instance error.

HERE IS MY CODE THAT IS THROWING THE ERROR

After each photo is taken I call this code to store the image

```
 [self.arrSlidshowImg addObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(flippedImage, 1.0)];
```

Then when the last photo is taken I simply call this code but it throws an error.

```
NSArray *myArray = [self.arrslideshow copy];
    [AHIImagesToVideo saveVideoToPhotosWithImages:myArray
                            animateTransitions:YES
                            withCallbackBlock:^(BOOL success) {
                                if (success) {
                                 NSLog(@"Successs");
                                                   } 
                                 else {
                                    NSLog(@"Failed");
                                                  }
                                                }];
```

YET THIS FORMAT WORKS PERFECT
I tried it with images from my app bundle.

```
NSArray * testImageArray = @[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.png"]];
    [AHIImagesToVideo saveVideoToPhotosWithImages:testImageArray
                            animateTransitions:YES
                            withCallbackBlock:^(BOOL success) {
                                if (success) {
                                 NSLog(@"Successs");
                                                   } 
                                 else {
                                    NSLog(@"Failed");
                                                  }
                                                }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to UIImageJPEGRepresentation returns an NSData object.  In your example that "works", you are putting UIImage objects into the array.  I suspect you just need to convert your NSData objects to UIImage objects before adding them to arrSlidshowImg.

Also, you might not need to do that copy on the array, since an NSMutableArray is actually an NSArray.